# Regex to match certain value in JSON

Tags: regex, jmeter

Working with Jmeter and have a response that is bugging me a bit.

```
{"iTotalRecords":19844,"iTotalDisplayRecords":19844,"aaData":[["20025","S1409117192","123vn","24 Feb 2014 21:30","1","1","0","0"],["20024","S1409336659","123vn","24 Feb 2014 21:06","4000","4000","0","0"],["20023","S1409509024","123vn","24 Feb 2014 21:03","4000","0","0","4000"],["20022","S1409347541","123vn","24 Feb 2014 21:01","4000","0","0","4000"],["20021","S1408224820","123vn","18 Feb 2014 23:34","4000","4000","0","0"],["20020","S1406490372","123vn","05 Feb 2014 17:04","2000","2000","0","0"],["20019","S1406876597","123vn","05 Feb 2014 16:59","2000","2000","0","0"],["20018","S1405014730","123vn","30 Jan 2014 18:11","2000","2000","0","0"],["20017","S1405306741","123vn","29 Jan 2014 21:25","2000","2000","0","0"],["20016","S1405175540","123vn","29 Jan 2014 18:06","2000","2000","0","0"]],"error":""}
```

I'm trying to return the value 20025 that is the first one after the aaaData, using regex

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks like JSON text. Probably easier to just decode the json into a native structure and accessing it natively.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you're getting a JSON answer. JMeter supports JSONPath language via a plugin which provides [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (you'll need `Extras with Libs Set`)

Relevant JSONPath query for your `20025` would look like:

```
$.aaData[0].[0]
```

See [Parsing JSON](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide on how to build JSONPath queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
"aaData":\[\["([^"]+)"
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/eX2rC0

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following regex:

```
(?<="aaData":\[\[")([^"]+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/sM4cE2